# Understanding the linebreak at the beginning of itemize

Tags: lists, line-breaking, itemize

I have a fundamental problem in understand how latex is typesetting documents.
Consider my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin = 0.75in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\section*{ABC}
abc
\section*{ABC}
\begin{itemize}
    \item abc
\end{itemize}
\textbf{ABC}\\
abc\\  
\textbf{ABC}\\
\begin{itemize}
    \item abc
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The output it produces is :- 
[image: latex-out]

Now this is fundamentally problematic. When I changed

```
\section*{ABC} 
abc
```

to

```
\section*{ABC}
\begin{itemize}
    \item abc
\end{itemize}
```

then only the abc got a bullet beside it without any changes in formatting.

However, when i do the same operation after a new line , as in the code

```
\textbf{ABC}\\
abc\\  
\textbf{ABC}\\
\begin{itemize}
    \item abc
\end{itemize}
```

then for some reason the itemize is adding a new line before rendering the list. Why?

Comment: Why would you put a forced line break before an `itemize` environment anyway? More to the point, why use forced line breaks at all?

Comment: @IanThompson I have a general format (defined using newcommand) in which I am printing the header using \textbf{XYZ}\\ and then writing some content after that. In some cases the content starts with itemize. So even though I wouldn't use a linebreak before an itemize, it's the format which is making me do so. In any case, I would like to understand what is happening.

Comment: `\textbf{XYZ}\\ ` isn't a very good way to produce a header.

Comment: It's happening because you're enforcing a line break ??

Comment: @IanThompson Two things. 1) What is the better way? subsections? Basically I had a \textbf{ABC}\hfill{2014-15}\\ . If I don't use the line break after the above line and use itemize after that, then I get a space character after the 2014-15 in the same line which I don't want, forcing me to use a line break after 2014-15. How to get rid of this problem?

2)I would still want to understand why this is happening

Comment: Use the optional parameter of `\\ ` - see my comments below. That's all I can think of if you cannot remove the `\\ `. What is that `\hfill{2014-15}` for? What does it do? I'm not too familiar with `\hfill`. And formatting tip: mark code with backticks `, so we can see it _is_ code.

Comment: Note: `\hfill{2014-15}` looks like a macro `\hfill` with one mandatory argument and possibly one or more optional ones. `\hfill` is a constant skip though, equivalent to `\hskip 0pt plus 1fill`. So why the braces?

Comment: Furthermore, unless I'm much mistaken, putting `\hfil` after that should gobble up any subsequent space characters and be ignored since `\hfill` is "stronger" in its stretching power. Try that. It should allow you to remove the `\\ ` without getting the annoying extra blank space character. I don't really use those commands, so if it doesn't work, I either remember badly, or the author of the document I remember reading this in wrote a wrong thing there. I'd favor the former.

Comment: I've tested this and it works. Before I edit my answer @NavinChandak, is your format exactly `<Header text> \hfill 2014-15`, <Header text> being the title in the header, or is there more?

Comment: @NavinChandak have you seen my last comment just above this one?

Comment: @NavinChandak I decided not to wait and edited the answer. Do look at it. You can also try seeing what happens by removing the `\\` altogether and using a double line feed instead.

Answer (score 4):

Let's see what happens when you type `\begin{itemize`. Now that should turn into `\itemize`, whereas `\end{itemize}` turns to `\enditemize`. Let's see what `\itemize` does:

```
\def\itemize{%
  \ifnum \@itemdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \edef\@itemitem{labelitem\romannumeral\the\@itemdepth}%
    \expandafter
    \list
      \csname\@itemitem\endcsname
      {\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}%
  \fi}
```

This is taken from `latex.ltx`, a file of LaTeX kernel definitions. So it checks if you are beyond the third level of `itemize` and if so issues the `\@toodeep` error, otherwise it advances the counter for the `itemize` level and defines `\@itemitem` to be `labelitem` plus `\@itemdepth` in roman numerals. Then it uses the `\list` command with arguments `\csname\@itemitem\endcsname`, i.e. `\<whatever there is in @itemitem>`, e.g. `\labelitemi` if `\@itemdepth` is 1, which is the reason for the `\expandafter` which is needed to expand `\@itemitem` before `\list` takes its arguments, and the second argument is `{\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}`, where `\hss` is a variable space which sort of decides where to put the item label, and `\llap` means the label can go outside the left margin. So let's look at `\list`, again from `latex.ltx`.

```
\def\list#1#2{%
  \ifnum \@listdepth >5\relax
    \@toodeep
  \else
    \global\advance\@listdepth\@ne
  \fi
  \rightmargin\z@
  \listparindent\z@
  \itemindent\z@
  \csname @list\romannumeral\the\@listdepth\endcsname
  \def\@itemlabel{#1}%
  \let\makelabel\@mklab
  \@nmbrlistfalse
  #2\relax
  \@trivlist
  \parskip\parsep
  \parindent\listparindent
  \advance\linewidth -\rightmargin
  \advance\linewidth -\leftmargin
  \advance\@totalleftmargin \leftmargin
  \parshape \@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
  \ignorespaces}
```

Again, there is a check as to whether you are nesting more than 5 lists, if so we have `\@toodeep`, otherwise we advance the number of nested lists by `\@ne`, i.e. 1. Then we have three lengths set to 0 (`\z@` is `0pt`), then the command `\@list<roman numeral of list depth>` (e.g. `\@listi` if we are on the first level of nesting) is used. `\@listi` and so forth are not in `latex.ltx`, nor in `plain.tex` or `list.tex`, so I don't know where to look. `\@itemlabel` is defined as the first argument, then `\makelabel` is set to `\@mklab`, which is `\def\@mklab#1{\hfil #1}`. The conditional `\@nmbrlist` is made false, argument 2 is executed, with a `\relax` probably to separate it from what follows, then `\@trivlist` is executed, then there are a couple of length assignments, and then there is `\ignorespaces`. Now `\@trivlist`, again in `latex.ltx`, is defined as follows:

```
\def\@trivlist{%
  \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
  \@topsepadd \topsep
  \ifvmode
    \advance\@topsepadd \partopsep
  \else
    \unskip \par
  \fi
  \if@inlabel
    \@noparitemtrue
    \@noparlisttrue
  \else
    \if@newlist \@noitemerr \fi
    \@noparlistfalse
    \@topsep \@topsepadd
  \fi
  \advance\@topsep \parskip
  \leftskip \z@skip
  \rightskip \@rightskip
  \parfillskip \@flushglue
  \par@deathcycles \z@
  \@setpar{\if@newlist
             \advance\par@deathcycles \@ne
             \ifnum \par@deathcycles >\@m
               \@noitemerr
               {\@@par}%
             \fi
           \else
             {\@@par}%
           \fi}%
  \global \@newlisttrue
  \@outerparskip \parskip}
```

I won't try to explain exactly what this does. I only see that `\@newlisttrue` is executed. `\item`, besides a few uninteresting things, calls `\@item`, which is:

```
\def\@item[#1]{%
    \if@noparitem
         \@donoparitem
    \else
        \if@inlabel
            \indent \par
        \fi
        \ifhmode
            \unskip\unskip \par
         \fi
         \if@newlist
              \if@nobreak
                   \@nbitem
              \else
                   \addpenalty\@beginparpenalty
                   \addvspace\@topsep
                   \addvspace{-\parskip}%
             \fi
         \else
             \addpenalty\@itempenalty
             \addvspace\itemsep
         \fi
         \global\@inlabeltrue
    \fi
 […]
}
```

With `\@newlisttrue`, we have `\@topsep` added as vertical space, supposing `\@nobreakfalse`, which gives us the vertical space. In the omitted part of `\@item` there is a `\@newlisttrue`, which means the following items only have `\itemsep` as vertical space. In fact, `\@donoparitem` has a `\vskip\@tempskipa` which is what gives the extra vertical space. That is used when you have two lists in a row, because there is "no par[agraph]" in between, and maybe after a `\\`, but anyway it's just 2pt extra with respect to `\@topsep`. So if you give `[-10pt]` as optional argument to `\\` in the header, the space should vanish. Anyway, as I said in the comment, a `\subsubsection` might be a better idea, or if you have a command for this header format you may want to make a star variant without the `\\`. As for the "it doesn't always have a linebreak" part, we can look at the definition of `\section`. I'll copy here the one from the `report` class:

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

So essentially a call to `\@startsection`. What is done directly by that command doesn't concern us, for all I can see. It ends by calling `\@sect`: `\@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}`. Looking at the definition of `\@sect`, it seems to do, in any case, nothing that influences `\item` or `\@item` or `\@donoparitem`. So we get to the end, and see `\@xsect{#5}`. Again, all this does that interests us is `\@tempskipa #1\relax`. Anyway it seems to set `\@noparitemfalse`, as a simple test demonstrates. So let me look at the definition of `\@item` in the hypothesis of `\@noparitemfalse`. Immediately after a `\section` command, a simple test shows `\ifhmode` is true and the other conditionals in the above part of the definition of `\@item` are all false. Which means all that part does is `\unskip\unskip \par` and `\global\@inlabeltrue`. But that is not `\section`'s fault. So it must be the default, and other commands take care of those conditionals. Which means answering this question gets *very* complicated and involves investigating every use of those conditionals. So I can't end this. And that was the "why does this happen" part, or the start of it.

As for the "how do I solve this" part, try this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\header}{\@ifstar{\@header}{\he@der}}
\newcommand{\@header}[1]{\textbf{#1}\hfill2014-15\hfil}
\newcommand{\he@der}[1]{\textbf{#1}\hfill2014-15\\}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent\header{Header 1}
Text for header 1, no itemize. \\
\header*{Header 2}
\begin{itemize}
\item Here is a Header with itemize. As you can see, no extra space is produced, and no extra vertical space is added.
\item Just remember the star after \verb"header" in this case.
\end{itemize}
Now let's put a simple paragraph: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer and so on. \\
\header{Header 3}
Nothing strange happens at all. I hope this solves your problem. Naturally, you can add the \verb"\noindent" to the command definition, to avoid the \verb"\parindent" for a header. You can also add a \verb"\par" or \verb"\\" before the header.
\end{document}
```

With this MWE, I get:

[image]

If that is not the format you want, you can tell me. Anyway the extra space is not present, and the extra space with `itemize` is not present. Of course, the header is treated as text, hence the vertical space between itemize and header. If you don't want that, I can try meddling with those conditionals mentioned above, or you can just add a `\vspace` to `\header` so that it appears only when you want it to appear.

Comment: For more info, you can look at `latex.ltx` and see the full definition of `\item`, `\@item` and `\@donoparitem`.

Answer (score 2):

[image: http://imgur.com/tlFDDUL]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin = 0.75in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\section*{ABC}
abc
\section*{ABC}
This is a really long paragraph depicting how \LaTeX\ typesets documents. This is a really long paragraph depicting how \LaTeX\ typesets documents. This is a really long paragraph depicting how \LaTeX\ typesets documents. This is a really long paragraph depicting how \LaTeX\ typesets documents.
\begin{itemize}
    \item abc
\end{itemize}
This is a really long paragraph that does not get indented because \LaTeX\ just left vertical mode from the \texttt{itemize} environment. This is a really long paragraph that does not get indented because \LaTeX\ just left vertical mode from the \texttt{itemize} environment. This is a really long paragraph that does not get indented because \LaTeX\ just left vertical mode from the \texttt{itemize} environment. 

This is a really long paragraph that shows how a whitespace between two paragraphs causes the second paragraph to get indented. No further formatting is needed. This is a really long paragraph that shows how a whitespace between two paragraphs causes the second paragraph to get indented. No further formatting is needed. This is a really long paragraph that shows how a whitespace between two paragraphs causes the second paragraph to get indented. No further formatting is needed.

A double slash \texttt{\textbackslash\textbackslash} forces a line break. A forced line break with the \texttt{itemize} environment subsequent thereto will first cause a line break, then \LaTeX\ will go into vertical mode to typeset the items. This involves an operation in vertical mode \emph{twice} rather than \emph{once}, as you intended it: \\
\begin{itemize}
    \item abc
\end{itemize}
Ufff, what an ugly space! Lesson learnt, I'd say!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi. Appreciate your effort! :) But I don't understand why latex needs to create a line break if the itemize appears after a forced line break. The answer by @mickg is technical and I am looking for the reason why latex does something like this.

Comment: Well if you are looking for the reason why it does so after a linebreak the point is it always does. I don't know if there is a way to check if just before a command another one has been executed, and thus to avoid the vertical space if `\\` has been used, but then one would need to redefine `\itemize` and that would be rather hard. If you are looking for a reason why it does that in general, well, I guess it makes sense to put some vertical space before a list in general. Anyway does your format allow you to add a `[…]` after the linebreak? If so, you can rule that vertical space explicitly.

Comment: You probably know, but `\\` can accept an optional parameter for vertical space after the linebreak, so you can specify a negative amount to eliminate the undesired vertical space. Otherwise, `\subsection*` or `\subsubsection` could be better ideas for headers.

Comment: @MickG I don't think that it always has a line break. Because when I use itemize after a \section*{XYZ}, then itemize doesn't start with a linebreak. (the itemized text starts from the same place as where a simple text would have started)

Comment: A slightly unrelated question. Is there a way to simulate section/subsection by a combination of font-size font-style and line breaks? (Because a section seems to have a very typical behaviour and doesn't seem to be a text followed by a line-break)

Comment: I've made a mess of backticks in my last comment :). Anyway if you want a header command you may like `\newcommand{\header}{\@ifstar{\@header}{\he@der}}` with `\newcommand{\@header}[1]{\textbf{#1}}` and `\newcommand{\he@der}[1]{\textbf{#1}\\}`, which of course requires being wrapped by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` unless in a package, and solves the problem of the extra vertical space by removing the linebreak in the starred alternative. You may also want to fiddle with vertical space after the header, adding in both `\he@der` and `\@header` a `\vspace` command at your pleasure.

Comment: You can also add an optional argument for the vertical space if you want to have control over it. For example `\newcommand{\@header}[2][<some default>]{\textbf{#2}\\\vspace{#1}}`. And similarly for `\he@der`.

Comment: As for the "it doesn't always have a linebreak", look at the definitions in `latex.ltx` and try to figure it out. I've done even too much with those definitions and am sort of sick of trying to crack that code. You will probably need to see what `\section*` does, and that probably also has to do with the class you're using.